# Disable video opening in gThumb

Tags: gthumb

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and gThumb 3.6. In gThumb, when I select with left click, or right click, one video or multiples, gThumb open video in big size thumbnail. It's really painful because I wish use options/functions of gThumb and not open it. How to disable the big thumbnail for video? Thanks in advance.